# Chrome mobile bug and crash on this line

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, input

On Android 5.1 and 6 (on android 7 it works fine) using Chrome mobile browser (66.0.3359.139) I am experienced chrome crash when I would like to open a file uploading dialog. I think the problem could be related to the accept property. I tried it 4 different android devices and the problem is the same.

Any idea?

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the latest Chrome (version 66).

Possible workaround is to remove `accept` attribute for Chrome 66 on Android < 7.x:

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.match(/.*Android [456]\..*Chrome\/66\..*/)) {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[accept="image/*"]')[0].removeAttribute('accept');
}
```

edit: The bug [has been confirmed](https://twitter.com/googlechrome/status/989816433461940224) by Google on twitter.

edit 2: The bug was fixed in Chrome 67 (67.0.3396.68). Patch: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f248278a23c62358aff045ce221cc2370c39f95b